# Getting import error while executing statements via livy sessions with EMR

Tags: apache-spark, jar, hadoop-yarn, amazon-emr, livy

I am trying to post statements to livy session with EMR 6.1.0. But i am unable to import the class(to my custom jar) which i am trying to execute.

Statement I am trying to post to a livy session -

```
   import com.path.to.Compactor 
   Compactor.compact(x, y, z)
```

`Compactor` class is present in `small-file-compactor-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar`

This is the error i am getting -

```
<console>:23: error: object path is not a member of package com
        import com.path.to.Compactor
```

When i try with `spark-shell --jars small-file-compactor-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar` the above code works fine.

I have tried passing this jar in `jars` argument in the livy REST API while creating the session and the application logs also suggests that its getting picked up and uploaded to hdfs.

Initially i was saving the jar in S3 and passing s3 link in the api. Then, i have tried putting in hdfs and then even tried to put the jar in `/usr/lib/livy/repl_2.12-jars/` directory so that it gets uploaded along with other jars. But that also didn't solve the `import` problem.

I have looked into the working directory of spark and the jar is present.

I have posted this `println(sc.jars)` statement and i get this

```
ArrayBuffer(file:/usr/lib/livy/rsc-jars/livy-api-0.7.0-incubating.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/rsc-jars/livy-rsc-0.7.0-incubating.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/rsc-jars/livy-thriftserver-session-0.7.0-incubating.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/rsc-jars/netty-all-4.1.17.Final.jar, hdfs:///user/livy/small-file-compactor-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/repl_2.12-jars/commons-codec-1.9.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/repl_2.12-jars/livy-core_2.12-0.7.0-incubating.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/repl_2.12-jars/livy-repl_2.12-0.7.0-incubating.jar, file:/usr/lib/livy/repl_2.12-jars/small-file-compactor-lib-1.0-SNAPSHOT-all.jar)
```

My jar is present here^

But why is spark not able to import the class?

Comment: I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like there is a bug with livy version of EMR 6.1.0, It does load the application classes to the JVM.

There is a workaround to solve this problem. You can use reflection.

```
{
    "kind": "spark",
    "code": "Thread.currentThread.getContextClassLoader.loadClass(\"com.path.to.Compactor\").getMethod(\"compact\", classOf[String], classOf[String], classOf[String]).invoke(null, Array(\"input 1\", \"input 2\", \"input 3\"))"
}
```

Comment: This works. But I have found an easier way. I have used a non-uber jar instead of an uber one. The problem with using an uber jar is explained here - https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LIVY-636?focusedCommentId=16923973&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-16923973.