How to use livy with external library
I try to use livy statement to submit a piece of scala code that reads lucene index and then read S3 files. As you can imagine, I try to use spark/livy to search data. Is that possible? How to include those jars into the session? I assume I should have them set up when calling the livy API to create the session.
btw, I successfully run lucene code inside ./spark-shell --jars jarsWithCommaSeparation.
Now back to livy, I find this link but it seems not free.
I also tried https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-import-External-Libraries-for-Livy-Interpreter-using/td-p/171812, Uploading jar to Apache Livy interactive session. This is my current code to create session:
    host = 'http://{0}:8998'.format(ip)
    data = {'kind': 'pyspark', 'numExecutors': 200, 
    'conf': 
        {
        'spark.submit.deployMode':'client',
        'spark.driver.memory': '10g',
        'spark.executor.memory': '2g',
        'spark.executor.cores': '2'}}
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    r = requests.post(host + '/sessions', data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

The error I see when submit livy statement code
<console>:27: error: object lucene is not a member of package org.apache

My code to submit statement code:
data = {
        'kind': 'spark',
        'code': textwrap.dedent("""
            import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
            import java.io.File;
            import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
            import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
            import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
            import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
            import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
            import org.apache.lucene.queryparser.classic.QueryParser;
            import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
            import org.apache.lucene.search.TotalHitCountCollector;
            import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
            import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;
            import org.apache.spark.SparkEnv;
            import org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.TaskContext;
            import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
            import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
            import java.net.URI;
            import java.nio.file.Paths;
            import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer;
            
            // some code
            """.format(index_location, query))
    }
    
    r = requests.post(statements_url, data=json.dumps(data), headers=headers)

Thanks.

Looks like same issue as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65654752/getting-import-error-while-executing-statements-via-livy-sessions-with-emr
